# Problems with C files

Tags: c, file

My code crashes,
Could you tell me what am i doing wrong?
if i isolate the FILE portion of the code it doesn't crash

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct student
{
    char* name;
    char* dorm;
};
#define NUM 3

int main()
{
    struct student students[NUM];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        char* naam;
        char* daarm;
        printf("Insert name of student #%d..\n",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&naam);
        students[i].name=naam;

        printf("Now enter name of the dorm\n");
        scanf("%s",&daarm);
        students[i].dorm= daarm;

    }

    FILE* file=fopen("C:/Users/Gigg/Desktop/ricchio.txt","w");
    if(file!=NULL)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
        {
            fprintf(file,"%s,%s",students[i].name,students[i].dorm);
        }

    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

i can't seem to find the answer anywhere,
furthermore,
the compiler also tells me that %s is expecting char* but that i give it char

Comment: If you get an error, it helps if we can see it.

Comment: also, try to write the file somewhere else, don't throw it into `C:/Users/Gigg/Desktop/ricchio.txt`.. too risky, like permission issues..

Comment: no errors,just two warnings
%s expects char* but i gave it char **
nothing more

Comment: Try removing the ampersands in `scanf("%s",&naam);` and `scanf("%s",&daarm);`.

Comment: i already did,
but when i do, the program crashes as soon as i write the first scanf string

Comment: try `%ms` instead of `%s` of `scanf`. Also `fclose(file);` move into if-block.

Comment: You're scanning to character pointers, but have you allocated any memory?

Comment: Ow. You have to also allocate memory for these strings. You can try transforming `char* naam;` into `char* naam = malloc (256);`, and the same for the other one.

Comment: lol  it says ms is not recognized,
why do i have to allocate using malloc?

Comment: An area for storing input is necessary.

Comment: i tried, gives the same two warnings and crashes anyway..
any idea?

Comment: `char* naam;` says "let's have 4 (on x86 or 8 on x86_64) bytes for a local variable, a pointer. If you are going to store a name, for example, your own, you gotta reserve than 4 bytes for actually storing it, and make it non-local so that it can be later used as part of the `student` struct. That's what `malloc` does here.

Comment: ah no! it worked , thanks man.. why char* naam=""; doesn't give the same result? this way should allocate on the stack... and then why it doesn't need the ampersand? is it because naam is already a pointer and alreaty contains an address?

Comment: _why char* naam=""; doesn't give the same result?_ But why would it? As a dumb check, if you don't specify the maximum length of the buffer to store the name anywhere, how do you expect the program to guess? And you got it right about the ampersand.

Comment: another question, as you can see i declared a struct in the preprocessor, with two strings... here i didn't malloc any space for them, so why aren't they throwing the same error?

Comment: Because struct isn't an array of char. When you use a struct like that it's allocated from the stack. You should get a book and follow it, you will learn about memory management in C. If you stumble around like this you will have a ton of problems and end up with face-full of bruises.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, so the two scanf char* variable threw an error because I didn't gave them any space to exist in, while the ones in the struct didnt need to have any space malloced because they use the buffer that i allocated on the stack by creating the struct?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

**Issues were**

1. Memory needed to be allocated.
2. You were attempting to close file using a null pointer.

NOTE: Add an error message if file cannot be opened. Magically sized memory should be improved. Handle lengthy user input.

See my 'NOTE's.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
    char name[1024]; // **NOTE**: magic number
    char dorm[1024]; // **NOTE**: magic number
};
#define NUM 3

int main()
{
    struct student students[NUM];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
      char naam[1024]; // **NOTE**: magic number
      bzero(naam, sizeof(naam));
      char daarm[1024]; // **NOTE**: magic number
      bzero(daarm, sizeof(daarm));

      printf("Insert name of student #%d..\n",i+1);
      scanf("%s",naam); // **NOTE**: input length       
      strcpy(students[i].name,naam);

      printf("Now enter name of the dorm\n");
      scanf("%s",daarm); // **NOTE**: input length
      strcpy(students[i].dorm,daarm);      
    }

    FILE* file=fopen("/tmp/test.txt",
                     "w");
    if(file!=NULL)
      {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
          {
            fprintf(file,"%s,%s\n",students[i].name,students[i].dorm);
          }

        fclose(file); // **NOTE** should only be done if non-zero value. 
    } else { // NOTE: error!!!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yep, it turned out i had to allocate space for those char* variables... bu only for the scanf ones, i left the ones in the struct as they were, without allocating space for them, but the program worked anyway.. do you know why?

Comment: Your fix (which I haven't seen yet) probably works because of the two assignments " students[i].name=naam " and " students[i].dorm= daarm; ". In practice I think (really) generally speaking programmers would opt to have separate memory for their read buffer and then copy it out of that into the structs. It establishes a clearer division of purpose. But it depends on your exact needs and in particular performance and design requirements. In your case you allocate the read buffer and then give it to the struct (I assume)